# Existence of a $\varphi \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\cos(\varphi)$ is transcendental

Tags: abstract-algebra, transcendental-numbers

Does anybody know an elementary proof that shows that there is a $\varphi \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\cos(\varphi)$ is a transcendental number? I have read about the Lindemann-Weierstrass Theorem but would prefer not to make use of it if at all possible. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: For any $x\in[-1,1]$ there exists $\varphi$ such that $\cos\varphi=x$; is there a transcendental number in the interval $[-1,1]$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pick any trascendental number $a$. Then all the numbers $\frac{a}{n}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ are trascendental, so there exists a trascendental number $ b \in (\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{2})$.

Then, call $\varphi = \arccos b$.

Comment: Accepted this answer because it works without requiring any specific knowledge of transcendental numbers (of which I dont have any), except the existence of at least one transcendental number. That was certainly easier than expected. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Hm, $1/e$ is transcendental and $\cos(0) = 1$, $\cos(\pi/2) = 0$. By the intermediate value theorem, there must be an $x \in (0,\pi/2)$ such that $\cos(x) = 1/e$.

Comment: So many transcendentals, so little time!

Comment: Well, the question did ask for just **a** transcendental number :-)

Comment: And $cos^{-1}(e^{-1})$ is explicit in my book...

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\cos \varphi$ is continuous for all $\varphi\in\mathbb{R}$, and the interval $\left[-1,1\right]$ is uncountable while there are only countably many algebraic numbers. Hence, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, there is some $\varphi_{0}\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\cos\varphi_{0}$ is transcendental.